# How to use for while or something like for while to sending data when trying to post something using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have some code like this :

```
<script>
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){name[i]: "name",}
</script>
```

and i know it's wrong because i want to use it on `$.post` and i don't know how can i do this

I tried this and this working well but I didn't add for while to this code because I don't know how to do this and i will show you where i want for while :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg",
      // for(i=0;i<=5;i++){name[i]: "name",} // it's my custom data and its not working
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to show the data you're trying to send in the question - up until then it's hypothetical

Comment: Hi user11299199, why do you need a while loop over $.post request ?? When you do a post can send a body object as data. So should prepare dat loop over $.post and save it as a const value string or something to setup inside the body object

Comment: you cannot add for loop in ajax param instead create the seperate var and pass to ajax params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way to do this and it's working:

```
<script>
    var data=[];
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){data.push(i)}
    $.post( "test.php", { 'data[]': data } );
</script>
```

And in `test.php` i will receive `$_POST['data']` as an array than i can do like this :

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST['data'])-1;$i++){
        print_r($_POST[$i]);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of objects and then post that array with all the data to the server.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {

    var data = []; // create an array

    //create your loop
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      var obj = {}; // create an object
      obj.name = "Insert name here"; // insert any property you need... you can even fetch the values from a dom object (like an input).
      data.push(obj); // add the object to the array;
    }

    // create your ajax request. Send it as JSON by converting the array (using JSON.stringify) and specifying the content type (json)
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
      JSON.stringify(data),
      function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      }, 'json');
  });
});
```